# Mkfs error undefined symbol: ext2fs_numeric_progress_ops

Tags: dynamic-linking, oracle-linux

I'm running a Oracle Linux 6.4 under Hyper-V.
I have to add a disk. So I add it in Hyper-V, Linux sees it when I run `fdisk -l` and I can see it. So I did a `fdisk /dev/sdb` then I created an extended partition, started from 1 and let other parameters as default.

Then I want to run a `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1` or ext4 (since I don't remember the difference, and I think there is no problem by choosing one or the other).

But the `mkfs.ext3` or `mk2efs` or `mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdb1` output this error:

```
 error symbol lookup : undefined symbol: ext2fs_numeric_progress_ops
```

I googled that, no answer at all. It never happened to me before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE1** : This is the output of `ldd /sbin/mkfs.ext3`

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff907fd000)
libext2fs.so.2 => /opt/appassure/lib64/libext2fs.so.2 (0x00007f7c126fc000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003290800000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x0000003290c00000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x0000003291800000)
libe2p.so.2 => /lib64/libe2p.so.2 (0x0000003291000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003368e00000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003369200000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003368600000)`
```

And when I run an `e2fsck /dev/sdb1` this is the output :

```
Error : ext2fs library is outdated !
        e2fsck 1.43-WIP (20-Jun-2013)
        Using library EXT2FS version 1.42.6, 21-Sept-2012
```

Comment: That's a linker issue. Did you build any of these programs yourself? If not, where did you get them from?

Comment: I don't know what is a linker issue. I didn't build anything right now. Just install the VM and add the disk. And try to put a fs on the partition. `Mkfs.ext3` and so were installed by default

Comment: If you didn't build any of the relevant packages, this is presumably a bug in your distribution, so I suggest you report it to the appropriate place. Also, please paste the output of `ldd /sbin/mkfs.ext3` in your question, please.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I'll update my answer asap. Do you think that can be Hyper-V fail ? But I installed the Linux Integrated Services (because I had problems with network cards/interfaces)

Comment: When I just type `mkfs.ext3` it says that a library version is obsolete or expired (I'll paste it in my question asap). I think this can be fix by running an `yum update something` but I ran a `yum update` and this has not been fixed (btw I didn't reboot, but do I need it ?).

Comment: The line `libext2fs.so.2 => /opt/appassure/lib64/libext2fs.so.2 (0x00007f7c126fc000)` looks suspicious. Why is this installed in `/opt`?

Comment: I installed Dell AppAssure (backup software) with the install.sh they provide. That's all. I can't answer why it's installed in /opt ... What can I do ? Sorry for being so newbie

Comment: Well, on my Debian system e2fslibs provides `libext2fs.so.2, and it is also `Priority: required`, When I try to remove it I get `WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed. This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!` So, why is this important program being installed by some piece of backup software? I suggest you read the documentation for Dell AppAssure and find out why they are doing this, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `e2fslibs` (part of [e2fsprogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E2fsprogs)
) is broken. Looking at the linker output for /sbin/mkfs.ext3 gives the following:

```
ldd /sbin/mkfs.ext3

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff907fd000)
libext2fs.so.2 => /opt/appassure/lib64/libext2fs.so.2 (0x00007f7c126fc000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003290800000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x0000003290c00000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x0000003291800000)
libe2p.so.2 => /lib64/libe2p.so.2 (0x0000003291000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003368e00000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003369200000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003368600000)`
```

The `libext2fs.so.2 => /opt/appassure/lib64/libext2fs.so.2 (0x00007f7c126fc000)` line is obviously wrong. By way of comparison, here is what my system returns.

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff2a00000)
    libext2fs.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libext2fs.so.2 (0x00007f4060158000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f405ff50000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f405fd28000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f405fb20000)
    libe2p.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libe2p.so.2 (0x00007f405f918000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f405f588000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f405f368000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f40603d0000)
```

According to the poster,

> I installed Dell AppAssure (backup software) with the install.sh they provide.

On my Debian system `e2fslibs` provides `libext2fs.so.2`, and it is also Priority: required. When I try to remove `e2fslibs` I get :

> WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed. This should
>   NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!

So the question is then why some backup software is installing an important piece of software on an RHEL derived system. In any case, that is clearly the problem.

Recommendation: read the documentation and/or ask the vendor of Dell AppAssure what is going on here. If this was installed by the backup software, it may break that software, so maybe it is not a good idea to remove it or (re)install the system `e2fslibs`.

It is also possible that the systems `e2fslibs` is still installed and the linker is ignoring it. Check for example

```
rpm -ql | grep e2fs
```

and/or the file location `/lib64/libext2fs.so.2`.

There are probably better ways of doing that. I don't use RH derived systems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i'll ask to a dell consultant what is the problem.

Comment: Solved by uninstalling the Dell Agent. Reported to Dell ! Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi Nico. Glad to hear your issue is solved. If the answer fixes your issue, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark. That is useful information for future people who might happen by here, because it tells them what solved the issue.